# Hide Virtual keyboard when using InputField

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I know how to hide or display Virtual Keyboard using `InputMethodManager`.

But I want to enter text in `EditText` using Physical keyboard but I don't want to display Virtual Keyboard in Unity 3D Android.

> How can I do that in Unity 3D?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as `EditText` in Unity. [`InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) is used to receive input from a device.

You can disable Virtual Keyword with `InputField` on Android. Not sure if this will work for other platforms.

Your InputField:

```
public InputField inputField;
```

Disable Virtual Keyboard:

```
inputField.keyboardType = (TouchScreenKeyboardType)(-1);
```

Enable Virtual Keyboard:

```
inputField.keyboardType = TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default;
```

---

If you run into weird issues, consider deriving your script from `InputField`, then disable Virtual Keyboard and finally, call the base `Start` function of the `InputField`:

```
public class HideVirtualKeyboard : InputField
{
    protected override void Start()
    {
        keyboardType = (TouchScreenKeyboardType)(-1);
        base.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way of dealing with it.

I tried this myself and it suppressed the keyboard as mentioned. I then built out an Android app to test, fired up the good ol' adb logcat and found that my terminal was flooded by index out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: @Esper This is why I like SO. You can always improve answer. If you know the "correct" way to do this that actually works then provide an answer.

Comment: You're right, it was wrong for me to say that this isn't the "correct" way of doing it because there is no "correct" way of solving this specific issue. What I should have said is that this isn't a viable solution since it yields an error at runtime.

Comment: No problem. This solves the issue but is just a workaround until Unity adds an official property or function to do so. Until then, we are stuck with this. Didn't get any error log at the time of writing this. Maybe things has changed in Unity but I don't think the error should prevent your game from running.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, but what you really want is to set `inputField.touchScreenKeyboard.active = false;` You may need to hold it false in a `LateUpdate`

```
[SerializeField] 
private bool keyboardEnabled = true;
// toggle this to toggle native keyboard activity
public bool KeyboardEnabled { get { return keyboardEnabled; } set { keyboardEnabled = value; } }

private void LateUpdate()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    if (inputField.touchScreenKeyboard != null && !keyboardEnabled)
    {
        inputField.touchScreenKeyboard.active = false;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: In a VR application where I never ever want to see the system keyboard, I put these lines inside an `Application.onBeforeRender`: `var ev = EventSystem.current; if (ev != null) { var go = ev.currentSelectedGameObject; if (go != null) { var inp = go.GetComponent<InputField>(); if (inp != null && inp.touchScreenKeyboard != null) inp.touchScreenKeyboard.active  = false; } }`